# Can only attach a script to a single Instantiate in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have run into a new and nifty problem and I'm hoping someone has some insight.

I need to instantiate a series of objects in the same location over time.  So in practice, an object is instantiated, waits 5 minutes, then is destroyed and a new object is instantiated.

I've looked into simply having a "stack" of invisible objects at the same coordinates and simply changing the "Set Active" but this feels clunky and inefficient, so I'm looking for a cleaner method.

Right now, I can instantiate an object every 3 seconds and attach a script to the first object, no problem.  The issue is that when I instantiate a *second* (or third or twenty-fifth) object, the script does not attach to the new object and I am left with an ever-growing pile of objects.

Can this instantiate code (pasted below) be adjusted so that a fresh script is attached to *every* instantiated object?

Alternate solutions are also encouraged :)

```
void MakeItSo()
{
    HowOften -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (HowOften <= 0) {
        Hello = Instantiate (MyObjects [Next], SpawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Hello.AddComponent<PM_WakeUpTimeToDie>();
        Hello.name =("fred_" + Next);
            HowOften = 3f;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code should work though. It should attach the script to the newly created object (but not to any others).

Comment: It will attach the script to the first object that is created, but I need it to attach a script to each object it creates.  If I run this under Update (for example) it creates a new object every three seconds, but only the very first object created has a script.

Comment: Please show me a screenshot of the inspector panel of one of these later created objects.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ccn2m9w8ch72vt/Inst_01.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I don't see what would be causing that. The code you've posted should never result in that behavior.

Comment: Yeah, there's no error messages or anything.  I'll keep digging.  With my luck there's a radio-button somewhere I missed.

Comment: Have you tried making the variable `Hello` local? Also coroutines might be a cleaner solution for this than just a timer. I can write you a small example solution once the actual problem is fixed.

Comment: No answer to your question, but "*I've looked into simply having a 'stack' of invisible objects at the same coordinates and simply changing the 'Set Active' but this feels clunky and inefficient, ...*' is a wrong assumption. It actually is more efficient and I dont see how any option would be intrinsically "cleaner" than the other.

Comment: Also to answer the question, the problem most probably is that after the first time you run it, `HowOften` no longer is `<= 0`. Kinda funny the line is even indented :)

Comment: Hi yes!  I'll play around with the HowOften numbers to see if that fixes it, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Hi Julian,  I started with a coroutine, but had a very similar result.  The second (and third and fourth, etc) objects just don't get scripts attached.

Comment: Hi yes!  The stack of objects might be cleaner codewise, but it offers a lot more opportunity for errors on the design-side that are potentially time consuming to debug.  That said, if I can't solve this in code, then I'll probably end up reverting to that as a solution.

Comment: *sigh* Solved it.  In the script I am referring to "this" as opposed to "this.gameObject" so it's destroying the script instantiation and leaving the object behind.  The "WakeUpTimeToDie" component I was adding is the second script used to destroy the object, and *that* script is where the problem lay.

Comment: @KimberlyUnger You can programmatically spawn the objects and set them to inactive. Activating and deactivating objects is more efficient than constantly instantiating and destroying them (bc they dont need to be cleaned up by garbage collection). Btw you can use @ to notify people in replies.